# On Unix on could I get a listing of all mp3 files inside a directory containing other directories with their full path?

Tags: unix, directory, find, search

Someone said to me use the `find` command but I'm not exactly sure how to do it.

Basically I need this:

suppose I have a folder called `dir1` and it contains three sub-directories (`dir2`, `dir3` and `dir4` respectively) and suppose there might be mp3 files in all of the aforementioned directories.  I would like to run a terminal command on dir1 that would search recursively through all the folders and list full paths of where it finds mp3 files. I need the full paths so that I know exactly where they were found.

Output should look something like this:

```
/Users/joeschomoe/dir1/Daft Punk - Around The World.mp3
/Users/joeschomoe/dir1/dir2/Jimi Hendrix - All Along The Watchtower.mp3
/Users/joeschomoe/dir1/dir2/Jimi Hendrix - Purple Haze.mp3
/Users/joeschomoe/dir1/dir3/Rolling Stones - Gimme Shelter.mp3
/Users/joeschomoe/dir1/dir4/Simon and Garfunkel - The Boxer.mp3
```

Would anyone know how to do this with `find` or some other Unix command I'm not aware of?

Any help would be gladly appreciated in advance. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find dir1 -name '*.mp3' -print` will do it.  `-name` and `-iname` are case-sensitive and case-insensitive matches for find.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much. This will help. Now I have one more thing to ask even though you've already been so helpful. How would I adjust the regular expression so that I can find more than one type of music file. Say, m4a files for example. I tried  '*.mp3|*.m4a' but it didn't work.

Comment: Reading the manual page should help, but `-name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.m4a'` will do what you want.